# How Array of our custom classes work with foreach without implemented IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, ienumerable

This long title already contain all my question so i just want to give example

```
MyClass[] array
```

How this array work with Foreach without implement IEnumerable interface's method ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) implements IEnumerable. Quote from the doc:

> In the .NET Framework version 2.0, the
>   Array class implements the
>   System.Collections.Generic.IList(T),
>   System.Collections.Generic.ICollection(T),
>   and
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(T)
>   generic interfaces. The
>   implementations are provided to arrays
>   at run time, and therefore are not
>   visible to the documentation build
>   tools. As a result, the generic
>   interfaces do not appear in the
>   declaration syntax for the Array
>   class, and there are no reference
>   topics for interface members that are
>   accessible only by casting an array to
>   the generic interface type (explicit
>   interface implementations). The key
>   thing to be aware of when you cast an
>   array to one of these interfaces is
>   that members which add, insert, or
>   remove elements throw
>   NotSupportedException.

Answer (score 3):

The following is from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb8xew9.aspx)

> In C#, it is not absolutely necessary
>   for a collection class to inherit from
>   IEnumerable and IEnumerator in order
>   to be compatible with foreach. As long
>   as the class has the required
>   ***GetEnumerator, MoveNext, Reset, and Current members***, it will work with
>   foreach. *Omitting the interfaces has
>   the advantage of enabling you to
>   define the return type of Current to
>   be more specific than Object, which
>   provides type-safety.*

Comment: For type safety you can (and should) implement IEnumerable<T>

Comment: I've not found a case where I couldn't just use IEnumerable<T> in my own code, I was just answering the original question of how to get foreach working without using the IEnumerable interface.

Answer (score 1):

The framework type Array implements IEnumerable...therefore, any array in .NET (of any type) implements IEnumerable.

Answer (score 1):

foreach does not require from type to implement IEnumerable interface, it just needs GetEnumerator() method.

Comment: The class needs to implement all the IEnumerable methods, not just GetEnumerator()

Comment: @Steve: `IEnumerable` only has a single method, `GetEnumerator`!

Comment: That's what I get for answering questions first thing in the morning.  I was filling in from the MSDN information in my answer on this question, which indicates additional methods are required, which are on the IEnumerator interface.